# How to pass a buffer to write() without allocating memory for it

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

It's hard to phrase the question, but I'll try.
I want to test performance of my usb connection, therefor I'm using gadgetfs on an ambedded device so I can just do a write to a filedescriptor and the data is sent to the host.
But when I want to send large amounts of data, I cannot allocate as much data as I want to.

```
write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

Is there a way to pass a pointer to somewhere in memory where it can actually read `nbyte` Bytes?
I can't allocate an array or a vector of the size that I want to send. cause I get an "Cannot allocate memory" error.

Comment: Could you allocate less and send in a loop? Or is that not possible with the environment you're using? Does it _need_ to be a single write?

Comment: If you can use multiple write calls, then allocate smaller memory (whatever possible) then send same data multiple times in loop.. so you can profile write speed with single allocation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your OS has `MAP_ANONYMOUS` or `/dev/zero` then you could `mmap` that into your virtual address space up to the maximum possible mapping and read from there.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

void * zeroed_memory = mmap(NULL, nbytes, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

This will allocate a continuous mapping of length `nbytes` to a single zeroed out read-only page and thus does not actually use any physical memory. You can read the whole array (and will only get zeroes), but you can not write to it.

Most systems will limit your maximum continuous virtual mapping though due to physical hardware restrictions. Current x86_64 Linux generally supports 64TB long mappings.

Note: some systems (OS X for instance, maybe other BSD based have `MAP_ANON` instead of `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, consult `man 2 mmap` to find out the exact one).

If `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is not supported on your system, but `/dev/zero` is then an equivalent method is:

```
void * zeroed_memory;
int fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY);
if (fd > 0) {
    zeroed_memory = mmap(NULL, nbytes, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `write` function will take whatever address you give it, and (attempt to) write `nbyte` bytes from that address onwards. As long as the memory is possible to read, this should work fine.

If you want to send more than a few kilobytes, it is often better to do that as multiple writes of a relatively small size (say 4KB), and use a loop to complete the write.

Comment: The thing is, for some reason, I have to (host side) read every `write()` that I perform on the gadget. So when I loop over the write, the host has to read the 4 bytes before I can call the next `write()`.

Comment: Are you saying that if you send 1MB from the target, the host has to read that as a single 1MB read, or it will "skip" data? That seems rather weird to me. But yes, eventually there will be some blocking at some point or another, and you will need to wait for the other end to "catch up". That's why I suggested 4KB at a time, as a good compromise between writing a single word and many hundreds of KB or MB at a time. Not sure what other answer you actually expected - I don't think there is any other solution.

Comment: I might suggest using `writev()` if the written data repeats. You can give an iovec pointing to the same buffer several times.

Comment: `writev` only helps if you want to write THE SAME data multiple times. It's not clear from the OP if that's the desire.

Comment: @Hasturkun That actually helped a lot! Since I want to test the performance I dont care what data I actually send. Thanks!

Comment: @MatsPetersson: That's the primary reason I posted it as a comment, rather than an answer